# Stopping an iterate loop by a condition and returning the value that matched the condition

Tags: haskell, newtons-method

I'm trying to implement the Newton-Raphson method on Haskell, and so far I have managed to get it working by using the `iterate` function, but the problem is that it retuns an infinte list due the nature of the iterate function, so I'm looking to find a way of stopping the loop when the value obtained in an iteration falls into a set margin of error, and returning said value

I looked some blog posts and even some questions on here, but I'm fairly new to haskell and not fully versed on the syntaxis, so for me reading code exmples or documentation is really hard by now.

Definitions of f(x) and g(x) (the derivative) are irelevant:

```hs
newton x0 = iterate step x0
    where step xn = xn - ((f xn)/(g xn))
```

I'm currently working by taking the first elements of the list given, using `take 4 $ newton 3.5` in the GHCi prompt, but the list returned by `iterate` is infinite, so I cannot use a tail function on it.

My idea is to set a constant somewhere, `margin = 0.0001` or something like that, and when the last iteration of the newton function falls behind the margin, the `iterate` function stops, and I have the final result

Comment: Maybe you want to consider `takeWhile`.

Comment: "*the list returned by `iterate` is infinite, so I cannot use a tail function on it.*" Why not? `tail` works fine on infinite lists.

Comment: Tangential note: if you want to use `newton` with different functions and margins, you might it useful to pass `f`, `g` and `margin` as arguments.

Comment: How about the `until` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variation of duplode's answer that only uses standard functions:

```
newton :: Double -> Double
newton x0 = (snd . head . dropWhile (not . goal)) (zip approxs (tail approxs)) 
    where
    approxs = iterate step x0
    step xn = xn - (f xn / g xn)
    goal (xa, xb) = abs (xb - xa) < margin
```

To determine whether our goal has been reached, we need to examine adjacent pairs of elements of the infinite list produced by `iterate`. To do that, we use the standard trick of zipping up the list with its own tail. (If you're feeling extra cheeky, consider using `(zip <*> tail) approxs` instead of `zip approxs (tail approxs)`. That way you don't have to mention `approxs` twice in the expression, which is admittedly a bit pointless.)

This gives us an infinite list of pairs, from which we drop elements until the difference between components of a pair gets small enough. At that point we extract the head of the remaining list (a pair) and take the second component.

Comment: I'd say this answer is a definite improvement: if "you want to test pairs of consecutive values", you are better off literally testing *pairs* of values :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to test pairs of consecutive values generated by `newton`. That means `dropWhile` from the Prelude won't be quite enough, as it only tests individual elements. Instead, you can use something like this [`dropWhileList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.4.2.0/docs/Data-List-Utils.html#v:dropWhileList) from *MissingH*:

```
newton :: Double -> Double
newton x0 = dropWhileList (not . goal) (iterate step x0) !! 1
    where
    step xn = xn - ((f xn)/(g xn))
    goal (xa:xb:_) = abs (xb - xa) < margin
    goal _ = False
```

`!! 1` give you the second element of the list. While it is a partial function (it fails if the list doesn't have a second element), here it is safe to use (as `iterate` generates an infinite list, you will have a result as long as the Newton's method converges).

Answer (score 0):

Picking up [oisdk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4892417/oisdk)'s suggestion of using [`until`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:until)...

```
until :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

... for an implementation that doesn't literally generate a list:

```
newton :: Double -> Double
newton = snd . until goal (move . snd) . move
    where
    step xn = xn - (f xn)/(g xn)
    move xn = (xn, step xn) -- The cheeky spelling is (,) <*> step
    goal (xa,xb) = abs (xb - xa) < margin
```

It is worth it comparing this with [melpomene's `zip`-based implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56203334/2751851) and noting the parallels.